# Check if an unknown variable is set in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I want to check if a variable is set or not.
I saw severeal post about this topics but not for the following use case.
In my case, I have an infinite number of variable ( BASE1 ... BASEn) and I want to check if BASEX variables was defined or not.

```
BASE="BAS0"
BASE1="BAS1"
BASE2="BAS2"
BASE3=""

var="";
cpt=0;
while true
do
    if [ $cpt -eq 0 ];
    then
            if ! ${BASE+false};
            then
                    echo "BASE:${BASE}is set";  ### -->  Ok it works
            else
                    echo "NOT set";
                    break;
            fi
    else
            if [ -z BASE${cpt} ];  ### ---> don t work
            then
                    if [ "BASE${cpt}" = "" ];
                    then
                            echo "BASE:${BASE}is set"; 
                    else
                            echo "BASE:${BASE}is empty ! ==> exit";
                            exit 0;
                    fi
            else
                    val="BASE${cpt}"
                    echo "$val NOT set";  ### -->  Always here !
                    break;
            fi
    fi
    cpt=`expr $cpt + 1`;
done
```

I tried severeal ways but whithout success :

```
if [ -z BASE${cpt} ]; ### ---> don t work
if ! ${BASE${cpt}+x}; ### ---> don t work
...
```

How can I do ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are constructing the name of the variable dynamically, you probably need an indirect reference:

```
var="BASE$cpt"
if [ -z "${!var}" ]
```

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you should use an array instead.

```
base=(BAS0 BAS1 BAS2 "")
for ((i=0; i<=4; ++i)); do
    echo "$i: ${base[$i]-false}"
done
```

Incidentally, you should probably use lowercase for your variable names, in keeping with the convention that uppercase is reserved for the shell's internal use.